# How to limit full payload size in spring-boot-starter-web?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to limit the full rest request size (including headers/body etc.). Is their a way to do that via configuration or via code?
I've tried the follwoing but it doesn't work.

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=1MB
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this config in src/main/resources/application.properties

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=1024KB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=1024KB
```

You can check this on the default documentation https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

Comment: As I mentioned I tried this and it didn't work.In addition, as far as I understand, it's enforced only on specific content types (application/json is not one of them). I am looking for something that will be relevant to all rest actions and content types